# В NetBeans не запускается GlassFish

Tags: glassfish, java

Здравствуйте. Решил приступить к изучению Spring. Пришлось работать с GlassFish. Моя среда разработки NetBeans. Все установил, первый запуск - все проходит гладко. Как только приходится прервать процесс или остановить сервер GlassFish, второй раз он уже не запускается, пишет такое:

> Развертывание на месте на C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\Мои документы\NetBeansProjects\HelloSpring\build\web
>   GlassFish Server, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
>   C:\Documents and Settings\Администратор\Мои документы\NetBeansProjects\HelloSpring\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1050: Модуль не развернут.
>   Подробные сведения приведены в протоколе сервера.

В Логи вообще ниче не пишет. Так как бы ни что не приводит в действие запуск сервера. Нашел решение :

> Решение найдено! Нужно создать новый
>   домен. Прошу заметить, это не
>   означает, что стандартный порт был
>   занят. Я удалил GlassFish из списка
>
> серверов NetBeans'a и добавил его
>   заново руками - не взлетело. Потом
>   попробовал тоже самое и создал вместо
>   дефолт-домена, другой домен на том же
>   порту (8080). Все заработало.

Заработало. Один раз. После остановки сервера, та же ситуация. Помогите, в чем может быть проблема, уже 2 полных дня убил на этот дурацкий вопрос.

Comment: Какие версии нетбинса и глассфиша? Был где-то баг похожий, там несовместимость восьмого нетбинса и четвертого глассфиша наблюдались

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй изменить путь для твоего проекта так, чтобы в нём не было русских букв..(если посмотришь domain.xml то внутри в самом конце будут данные для твоего проекта задеплоеного на сервер

---

> application context-root="/WebApplication3" object-type="user" 
>   directory-deployed="true" name="WebApplication3"
>   location="file:/C:/NetBeansProjects/WebApplication3/build/web/">
>   property name="appLocation" value="file:/C:/NetBeansProjects

) 
если в пути к папке твоего проекта, или в имени твоего проекта, будут русские буквы, то в файле ты найдешь - **кракозябры** :

> application context-root="/Library_2" object-type="user" 
>   name="Library_2" directory-deployed="true"
>   location="file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Aly/ͮ襲0寪etBeansProjects/Library_2/build/web/">
>   property name="appLocation" 
>   value="file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Aly/ͮ襲0寪etBeansProjects/Library_2/build/web/">

..........................................................................
а если русских букв нет, то и путь будет правильный.
Когда изменишь путь своего проекта без русских букв, то и 
после этого сможешь его деплоить, стартовать , перезагружать и т.д.

Как сейчас этого избежать:

Вариант 1.

1. Создавая проект, указывай путь к проекту и имя проекта, без русских букв.

Вариант 2.

1. Удалить все секции {application} из файла domain.xml c русскими буквами.
2. Перезапустить NetBeans.

Вариант 3.

1. Правой кнопкой на твоём проекте.
2. Если имя проекта содержит русские буквы, выбрать переименовать проект.
3. Указать имя без русских букв.
4. Если папка проекта содержит русские буквы, выбрать переместить проект.
5. Указать путь к папке проекта без русских букв.